# Calculate $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt{n^4+an^3+2n^2}-n^2$ for $a \ge 0$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I've tried to simplify $\sqrt{n^4+an^3+2n^2}-n^2$ the following way:

\begin{align}
        &\sqrt{n^4+an^3+2n^2}-n^2\\\\
        &\frac{(\sqrt{n^4+an^3+2n^2}-n^2)(\sqrt{n^4+an^3+2n^2}+n^2)}{(\sqrt{n^4+an^3+2n^2}+n^2)}\\\\
        &\frac{n^4+an^3+2n^2-n^4}{(\sqrt{n^4+an^3+2n^2}+n^2)}\\\\
        &\frac{an^3+2n^2}{(\sqrt{n^4+an^3+2n^2}+n^2)}\\\\
    \end{align}
But now I'm stuck.

Comment: Divide both the numerator and denominator by $n^2$. The final answer depends on the value of $a$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Diving the numerator and denominator by $n^2$ yields
$$
\frac{an+2}{\sqrt{1+\frac{a}{n}+\frac{2}{n^2}}+1}
$$
When $a>0$, the limiting value of this expression is $\infty$, while, if $a=0$, the limiting value is $1$.

Comment: Thanks. Sometimes I feel so dumb for not seeing something so obvious. I guess its only obvious after you've seen it

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, from your last step

$$\frac{an^3+2n^2}{(\sqrt{n^4+an^3+2n^2}+n^2)}=\frac{an^3+2n^2}{n^2}\cdot\frac{n^2}{(\sqrt{n^4+an^3+2n^2}+n^2)}=$$

$$=(an+2)\cdot\frac{n^2}{(\sqrt{n^4+an^3+2n^2}+n^2)}\sim \frac12(an+2)$$

Comment: Thats also a good answer. Thanks

Comment: Thanks! You are welcome. Bye